# SQL switch -- Fill in 'n/a' for blank cells

Tags: sql, ms-access, switch-statement, jet

My query isn't working as I expect it to.
I am trying to create `best_id` and where blanks are set to `'n/a'` .

Also I use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` connection via excel to do an internal query within my workbook.

Here is a table showing the conditions and my desired `best_id` value for each condition:

```
condition                                          best_id value
------------------------------------------------   ------------------------------
bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] is not blank      master.[Identifier]
bbg_cusip.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] is not blank   replace(master.[Identifier],' cusip','') & ' cusip'
bbg_isin.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] is not blank    replace(master.[Identifier],' isin','')  & ' isin'
master.[Identifier] is not blank                   master.[Identifier]
all four of those fields are blank                 'n/a'
```

I listed those conditions in order of precedence; the first row where the condition is True will be the one which determines my `best_id` value, and any following conditions should be ignored.

It seems to me that `Switch()` should be the right tool for this job.  However my attempts (see below) so far have not produced the results I want.

So is my problem that `Switch()` is not the right tool for this job or that I haven't been able to figure out how to properly apply it for my needs?

Here are 2 of my failed attempts:

```
switch(
bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like '[#]N/A%',master.[Identifier],
bbg_cusip.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like '[#]N/A%',replace(master.[Identifier],' cusip','') & ' cusip',
bbg_isin.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like '[#]N/A%',replace(master.[Identifier],' isin','')  & ' isin',
master.[Identifier] is not null, master.[Identifier],
true,'n/a'
) as best_id,
```

**Tried**:

```
 switch(
bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like "[#]N/A*",master.[Identifier],
bbg_cusip.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like "[#]N/A*",replace(master.[Identifier],' cusip','') & ' cusip',
bbg_isin.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like "[#]N/A*",replace(master.[Identifier],' isin','')  & ' isin',
master.[ Identifier] is not null, master.[ Identifier],
true,"n/a"
) as best_id,
```

But I cannot seem to get "n/a" in blank cells. Should I try to use `iif` here? Tried `iif(master.[Identifier] is null ,"n/a",' '
)` instead of `"n/a"` aswell.

**expected result, currently its a blank cell where my 'n/a's are:**

[image]

Here are my joins at bottom of query,

```
from (([DB$] as master 
left join 
(select distinct [Identifier],[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] from [prev$]) as bbg_id
on bbg_id.[Identifier]=master.[Identifier])
left join
(select distinct [Identifier],[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] from [prev$]) as bbg_cusip
on bbg_cusip.[Identifier]= (master.[cusip] & ' cusip'))
left join
(select distinct [Identifier],[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] from [prev$]) as bbg_isin
on bbg_isin.[Identifier]= (master.[isin] & ' isin')
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'blank'? Empty string, or null?

Comment: Empty cell, I would like the empty cells of this column to be populated with `n/a`

Comment: If `bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes]` is blank, you want to return the text *"n/a"*.  And if `bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes]` is **not** blank, you want to return `master.[Identifier]`  Are both those statements correct?

Comment: @HansUp Yes sir, that is correct.

Comment: Good.  Thank you.  Notice there are only 2 possibilities which `Switch` can evaluate. Either `bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes]` is blank or is not blank.  After that, `Switch` considers its job is finished.  It will never evaluate those remaining fields (`bbg_cusip.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes]`, `bbg_isin.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes]`, and `master.[ Identifier]`).  Although I'm not sure what you want, I suspect `Switch` is not the solution.

Comment: Please clarify what should appear in your computed column, `best_id`, for the possible combinations of blank vs. non-blank in those other 4 columns.  Perhaps what you really need is 4 separate computed columns: `best_id1`; `best_id2`; `best_id3`; and `best_id4`

Comment: @HansUp I put a photo of what I expect. I'm guesing something wrong with my syntax. Does this make more sense now?

Comment: Not sure.  I don't understand the logic for what goes into `best_id` and the picture doesn't help.  Is this your strategy?  When all 4 of the source fields ... `bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes]`, `bbg_cusip.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes]`, `bbg_isin.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes]`, and `master.[ Identifier]` ... are blank `best_id` will be 'n/a'.  Otherwise `best_id` will be determined by the first of those fields which is non-blank and will be either `master.[ Identifier]` unaltered or `master.[ Identifier]` altered by `replace()`.  Is that correct?

Comment: @HansUp Correct, im going to add my joins at the bottom of my query to help. if you want I can continue this in a chat.

Comment: Can `master.[Identifier]` ever be blank?  Since that's the field you're using for the left joins, seems it should not be ever blank.

Comment: @HansUp in my actual sheet it does have blanks.

Comment: perhaps I should just use, `iif(master.[Identifier] is not null, master.[Identifier],
true,'n/a'
) as best_id,`

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard for `like` in MS Access is `*`, not `%`.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
switch(bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like "[#]N/A*", master.[Identifier],
       bbg_cusip.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like "[#]N/A*", replace(master[Identifier], " cusip", "") & " cusip",
       bbg_isin.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like "[#]N/A*", replace(master.[Identifier], " isin", "")  & " isin",
       master.[Identifier] is not null, master.[Identifier],
       true, "n/a"
     ) as best_id,
```

MS Access generally uses double quotes for strings rather than single quotes, so I changed those as well (although that is probably optional).

Comment: Thanks gordon. However I do use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` not sure if the syntax may be different then regular MS Access syntax.

Comment: any help gordon?

Comment: @excelguy . . . I'm not sure.  This looks like MS Access syntax to me.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access uses `*` for wildcard, not `%`.

Comment: this didnt seem to help, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Because you've tagged Ms Access,
you can use NZ(Expression, ValueIfNull) function to determine whether a string field is null or has empty string.
`(NZ(master.[Identifier],'') = ''), 'N/A',` => "N/A" if the field is null or ""

So your query could look like this.

```
    switch(
        (NZ(master.[Identifier],'') = ''), 'N/A',
        bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes]    not like '[#]N/A*',master.[Identifier],
        bbg_cusip.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] not like '[#]N/A*',replace(master.[Identifier],' cusip','') & ' cusip',
        bbg_isin.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes]  not like '[#]N/A*',replace(master.[Identifier],' isin','')  & ' isin'
) as best_id,
```

Comment: didnt seem to work, it is jet access syntax, does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition/value pairs translate easily to `Switch()` expression/value pairs.

```
Switch
    (
        Len(Trim(bbg_id.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] & '')) > 0, master.[Identifier],
        Len(Trim(bbg_cusip.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] & '')) > 0, replace(master.[Identifier],' cusip','') & ' cusip',
        Len(Trim(bbg_isin.[BbgType_MarketSectorDes] & '')) > 0, replace(master.[Identifier],' isin','') & ' isin',
        Len(Trim(master.[Identifier] & '')) > 0, master.[Identifier],
        True, 'n/a'
    ) AS best_id
```

I was uncertain what your "blank" values actually are.  Possibilities include:

1. Null
2. empty string (`''`)
3. one or more spaces, but no other characters

`Len(Trim([Field] & ''))` will treat those cases the same; `Len` will be zero.   So `Len(Trim([Field] & '')) > 0` identifies "non-blank" values.

The fifth expression, `True`, is only evaluated when none of the previous 4 expressions was `True`.  So that means all 4 of the source fields were "blank" and `Switch` should return *'n/a'*.